# AWS S3. Multipart Upload. Can i start downloading file until it's 100% uploaded?

Tags: file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Actually title was a question :)
Do AWS S3 support file streaming in case if file is not 100% uploaded? Client #1 split files into small chunks and start uploading them using Multipart Upload. Client #2 start downloading them from S3. So, as result client #2 don't need to wait until client #1 has uploaded the whole file.
Is it possible to do it without additional streaming server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not natively supported by S3.

S3 allows the individual parts of a multipart upload to be uploaded sequentially, or in parallel, or even out of their logical order, over an essentially unlimited period of time.

It is not until you send the `CompleteMultipartUpload` request that the parts are verified by S3 as all being present, and having the correct checksums, that the final object is assembled from the parts, and is created in the bucket (or overwrites the former object with the same key, if there was one) if the parts are all present and their integrity is intact.  Until then, the object -- as an object at the designated key -- does not technically exist, so it can't be downloaded.

Comment: Actually that's what i found out in a last few days :) Just wanted to make sure that it's technically impossible from AWS S3 side. We will implement this logic on our side. Thank you!

Comment: @RomanParaschak i´m on the same dilemma, could you share how did you solved it?